# Why the distinction between single-line and multi-line comments?

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, comments

In the languages like python, ruby, javascript, there is separate syntax for single-line and multi-line comments. I don't see the benefit of this complexity. Why, from a language design perspective, is there a distinction between the two? Using javascript as an example, here's the implementation:

```
// I'm a single-line comment!

/* 
I'm a 
multi-line
comment
*/
```

Why not simply (something like):

```
/* Just a comment */

/* 
Doesn't matter 
how many 
lines 
/*
```

Comment: Python does not have a separate syntax for single- and multi-line comments. It does, however, have multi-line strings, which are commonly used for documentation and actually have some function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- People need to comment out blocks of code at once
- People also need to comment out single lines

Commenting out a single line is faster when there’s only one change to make.

There *are* languages that only support comments with a starting and ending delimiter — C89 is a notable example (ever think C99 added `//` for a reason?). However, using the same starting and ending character would make a complete mess if you forgot to take one (or the other) out. Every comment following it would be flipped, and how would the compiler (if it’s a somewhat helpful one) know where the syntax error was?

Comment: C probably gained `//` comment support because everyone was supporting it anyway, that was probably more of a "normalization with standard practice" issue than a "we must have this wonderful feature" issue.

Comment: @muistooshort: I call primarily opinion-based on that! ;)

Comment: @muistooshort That just changes the rethorical question to "Why did everyone support `//` comments?" ;-)

Comment: And that's why this was rightfully closed and why no one should bother answering it. Anyone that's been around here long enough should know that questions like this will get shot down so why waste your time answering it?

Comment: @delnan: Because everyone's C and C++ compilers were mashed together. And that brings one more pointless step down a long chain of pointless opinions and speculations :)

Comment: @minitech: Thanks!  It sounds like what I wasn't seeing is that programmers want the ease of making single-line comments quickly (single delimiter), and multi-line comments necessarily need to be more complex (opening and closing delimiters).

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer is that single-line comments are faster to add.
For example, in JS you need 2 special characters to add single-line comment and 4 to add multi-line comment.